# Highlight text inside different html tags

Tags: javascript, html

I want to highlight **elvis presley**.

```
<div id="test">
    <p>elvis</p>
    <p id="tag1">my name is elvis</p>
    <p id="tag2">presley</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With js you can try something this:

**js**

```
var elvis = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var presley = document.getElementById("tag2")
elvis.style.color = "blue";
presley.style.color = "blue";
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2T5f8/5/)

Answer (score 0):

## jQuery method

*assuming you will always want the last words of `tag1` and `tag2`.*

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZH3dH/)**

---

**JS**

This finds the last word in both `tag1` and `tag2` then adds a `span` with the class `.highlight`

```
$("#tag1,#tag2").html(function(index, old) {
    return old.replace(/(\b\w+)$/, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight {
    background:yellow;
}
```

---

Using this JS as inspiration, it would be easy to manipulate the text similarly.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/5L4kW/1/

```
$("document").ready(function(){
highlightText('elvis');
highlightText('presley');
})    
function highlightText(val)
{
var src_str = $('div').html();
var term = val;
term = term.replace(/(\s+)/,"(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");
var pattern = new RegExp("("+term+")", "gi");
src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
src_str = src_str.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*    <\/mark>)/,"$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");
$('div').html(src_str);
}
```